# How Would I Calculate The Distance Between The Points Google Maps Api V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am working on a project and it is almost completed. The problem is that I am pretty new to Javascript and can't figure out how to do something that is probably pretty simple. Here is part of my code:

```
var dista;
var p;
var addrbounds;
var addrlat;
var addrlng;
var addr;

var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png",

new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),

new google.maps.Point(16, 32));

var center = null;
var map = null;
var currentPopup;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {

var address = document.myform.customer.value;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {

if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

var addrbounds = results[0].geometry.location; //get geocoded results into variable
var addrlat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var addrlng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
var p = new google.maps.LatLng(addrlat, addrlng);
var pt1 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

dista = pt1.distanceFrom(p); //calculate distance between the points

var di = (dista/1000);

document.myform1.memory.value = di; //add dist to memory text box

return;

} else {

alert(address + ' not found');

}

});

// desired spot for if statement regarding distance

var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

bounds.extend(pt);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

position: pt,

icon: icon,

map: map

});

var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: info,
maxWidth: 300

});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {

if (currentPopup != null) {

currentPopup.close();
currentPopup = null;

}

popup.open(map, marker);

currentPopup = popup;

});

google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {

map.panTo(center);

currentPopup = null;

});

}
```

Basically what it does is that the first thing that happens in the addMarker() function is geocode an address and then calculate the distance away from the address. That works just fine. The problem comes when wanting to get the get the distance out the geocoder to create an if statement to only add markers from the database if it is within a certain radius. As you can see, I try to move it to a text box. That seems to work but it is part of a loop and won't update with each running of the loop.

I have been stuck for a couple days so any help would be appreciated. I hate being so close to finished but stuck!

Edit:

I got it to work. This is how I did it:

```
var dista;    

var p;

var addrbounds;

var addrlat;

var addrlng;

var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png",

new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),

new google.maps.Point(16, 32));

var center = null;

var map = null;

var currentPopup;

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {    

var address = document.myform.customer.value;

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {

  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

  var addrbounds = results[0].geometry.location;

  var addrlat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();

  var addrlng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

  var p = new google.maps.LatLng(addrlat, addrlng);

  var pt1 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

  dista = pt1.distanceFrom(p);

  var di = (dista/1000);

  document.myform1.memory.value = di;

  document.myform1.memory1.value = addrlat;

  document.myform1.memory2.value = addrlng;

  return;

} else {

  alert(address + ' not found');

}

 });

var tstlat = document.myform1.memory1.value;

var tstlng = document.myform1.memory2.value;

var tstpt = new google.maps.LatLng(tstlat, tstlng);

var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

var distan = pt.distanceFrom(tstpt);

var tstdistance = (distan/1000);

if (tstdistance < 20){

// alert (tstdistance);

bounds.extend(pt);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

position: pt,

icon: icon,

map: map

});

var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({

content: info,

maxWidth: 300

});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {

if (currentPopup != null) {

currentPopup.close();

currentPopup = null;
}  
popup.open(map, marker);

currentPopup = popup;

});

google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {

map.panTo(center);

currentPopup = null;

});

}

else

 {

 return;

 }}
```

Now I just need to fix a map refresh issue and then the project is complete!

Comment: I looked at that already, but I can't get info out of the geocoder function. It all comes back as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot **get** anything out of a geocoder-callback, geocoding forces an asynchronous request, you'll never know from outside the callback, when the response arrives.

Instead of **getting** something from outside, you must **push** something to outside from the callback(as  you've done it already by setting the value of the textbox). You can also call another function from the callback and supply the distance as argument.