# How to pass reverse geocoded adress back to a variable

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, geocoding, reverse

how to 'simply' extract an adress value from geocoder 
my code looks like this:

a number of things before....

```
geocoder.geocode({latLng: 'mylatlon'}, function(results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                     if (results[0]) {
                    //alert(results[0].formatted_address);
                    thisadr=results[0].formatted_address;  
                         }}});';
```

a number of things after... like  e.g   map title : thisadr  or infowindow.content(thisadr
nope

it works perfectly though (if I trust alert) but I can't get the thisadr var out of here

I spent numerous hours trying to look for a decently straight forward solution to no avail

I then have a secondary problem 
I PHPbuild an html table to feed the infowindow

so at a point I will need to mix that html table with that thisadr variable

so far and grossly my infowindow looks like

```
var contenuInfoBulle'.$camindex.' =  \''.$phpbul.'\';
```

what I would like would be it to show

```
 var contenuInfoBulle'.$camindex.' = thisadr  \''.$phpbul.'\';
```

Comment: A link to live code would be very useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Would I Calculate The Distance Between The Points Google Maps Api V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608444/how-would-i-calculate-the-distance-between-the-points-google-maps-api-v3)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to answer my own questions

1/ by including all of what needed WITHIN the geocoder request while creating an indexed function and calling it afterwards for each indexed marker

```
echo 'function buildmarker'. ($camindex). '(location) {';
echo 'geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();';

echo "geocoder.geocode({'latLng': location}, function(results, status) {";
echo "   rue='Adresse &agrave; d&eacute;terminer';";
echo '   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {';
echo '        if (results[0]) {';
echo '          adress=results[0].formatted_address;';
echo "          elts=adress.split(',');";
echo '          rue=elts[0];';
echo '        }';

echo '      }';

echo 'var   contenuInfoBulle =  rue+\''.'<br>'.$phpbul.'\';';
echo 'var infoBulle = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contenuInfoBulle });';
echo 'var thisicon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("../img    /marker'.$coulgoog.$ajout.'.png",null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(25, 25));';
echo 'var optionscam= {position: location,map: macarte,title:  "'.$camindex.'     '.$shortcam.'"   ,icon: thisicon};';
echo 'var mark = new google.maps.Marker(optionscam);';
echo 'google.maps.event.addListener(mark, "click", function() {infoBulle.open(macarte, mark)});';
echo 'var optionsCercle = {center: location,map: macarte,radius: 20 ,strokeWeight: 0};';
echo 'var monCercle = new google.maps.Circle(optionsCercle);';


echo '    });';
echo '} ';            //func

///////////////////////


echo "var cam". ($camindex). " = new google.maps.LatLng(".$myloc.");";
echo "buildmarker". ($camindex). "(cam".($camindex).");";
```

2/ by mixing JS/googmap variable and prefab PHP/HTML content

```
echo 'var   contenuInfoBulle =  rue+\''.'<br>'.$phpbul.'\';';
```